# Navigating and sending data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

I created a navigation drawer. Now,navigation drawer requires all fragments. I want to send some information and move to this fragment which contains drawer from an activity. How do I implement this ? I am using `Intent(activityclass.this,fragment.class)` for navigation and `putExtra` for sending data. But the app crashes.

Comment: Maybe you need a good sample code. If you want your existing code fix, pls post them, the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not loaded using Intent. You need to use FragmentManager:

```
 Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();       
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

your approach needs some modification i would like to refer the below links for better ways

[official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

[Some good practises for your app communication](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/25/inter-fragment-communication/)